# recursive function and setTimeout() problem

Tags: javascript, canvas, settimeout

I have a script that draws a bunch of lines on canvas, but it's pretty intense so while rendering freezes browser for a few seconds. I added setTimeout() so that the browser wouldn't freeze and it effectively messed up my script. It's difficult to explain how, so I have two examples online:

Without setTimeout() : http://www.modwebsolutions.com/test1

With setTimeout() : http://www.modwebsolutions.com/test2

Note, that I only change a single line in the whole script, that is line 69:
without setTimeout(): `vLoop();`
with setTimeout(): `setTimeout(vLoop,1);`

Comment: can you how us the actual code of `vLoop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here, as hinted at by others, is that you are drawing the lines a quadrant at a time. As soon as the `SetTimeout` method is called and the first `vLoop` returns, the code carries on running into the next `drawVertical` which changes all the global variables and so on.

What you need to do is synchronise how you're calling vLoop and how you are changing the globals.

This is basically the solution:

Replace ...

```
drawVertical(c,-1*step,-1*stepInt,-1*bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2+50,y);
drawVertical(c,step,stepInt,bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2+50,y);
drawVertical(c,-1*step,-1*stepInt,-1*bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2-50,0); 
drawVertical(c,step,stepInt,bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2-50,0);
```

... with ...

```
var q = new Array();
q[0] = [c,-1*step,-1*stepInt,-1*bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2+50,y];
q[1] = [c,step,stepInt,bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2+50,y];
q[2] = [c,-1*step,-1*stepInt,-1*bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2-50,0];
q[3] = [c,step,stepInt,bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2-50,0];

drawQuadrant(q, 0);
```

Replace your `drawVertical` function with ...

```
function drawQuadrant(q, i)
{
    var r = q[i];

    c__ = r[0];
    step__ = r[1];
    stepInt__ = r[2];
    bigStep__ = r[3];
    xStart__ = r[4];
    xEnd__ = r[5];
    yStart__ = r[6];
    yEnd__ = r[7]; 


    vLoop(q,i);
}
```

change the `vLoop` function prototype to look like this ...

```
function vLoop(q,i)
```

and finally replace your recursive `vLoop` call (from within vLoop) with ...

```
if ((xStart__ > 0) && (xStart__ < window.innerWidth))
{
    setTimeout( function(){vLoop(q,i)}, 1 );
}
else if (++i < 4)
{
    setTimeout( function(){drawQuadrant(q,i)}, 1 );
}
```

The last block is where it ensures that the quadrants are not stepping over each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
drawVertical(c,-1*step,-1*stepInt,-1*bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2+50,y);
drawVertical(c,step,stepInt,bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2+50,y);
drawVertical(c,-1*step,-1*stepInt,-1*bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2-50,0); 
drawVertical(c,step,stepInt,bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2-50,0);
```

Your calling 4 recursive functions of `vLoop` at once. The problem here is that `setTimeout` is non-blocking where as recursion is blocking. So basically you now have all 4 of these drawVertical functions running in parallel rather then in sequence.

The other problem is that all 4 refer and mess with global state and your entire program breaks.

Comment: They're still single threaded, so to say they run in parallel isn't really accurate.

Comment: @NickCraver Time-spliced execution is them virtually running in parallel. How is using setTimeout different from time splicing?

Comment: @Raynos - You'll never be inside that method more than once at the same time, which is the definition of parallel :)

Comment: @NickCraver but you'll be inside the set of functions executed recursively more than once at a time. The individual funtion doesn't run in parallel but the recursive execution does.

Comment: @Raynos - It doesn't...at no point will any line of code he's running will be run simultaneosuly

Comment: I understand the problem, but then how do I make these functions run in sequence just with different arguments?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is what `setTimeout()` delays *all* that execution until later.  Unfortunately, by that point your global variables have all moved to their ending positions from the initial loop, since it completed before the first line was drawn.

If you moved your timeout further up (so the shared variables you're using aren't affected until draw time) you could achieve what you're after, for example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    drawVertical(c,-1*step,-1*stepInt,-1*bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2+50,y);
    drawVertical(c,step,stepInt,bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2+50,y);
    drawVertical(c,-1*step,-1*stepInt,-1*bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2-50,0);
    drawVertical(c,step,stepInt,bigStep,xStart,xEnd,y/2-50,0);
});
```

Then this would work (but it's dangerous, order isn't absolutely garunteed!)

[You can see a working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/zzUxQ/).

Comment: That's just delaying the whole drawing process till later. As soon as the block starts running, you still have the original problem of freezing the browser.

Comment: @Musaul - It'll be in a timed callback, but you can alleviate that with a non-0 value for the timeout duration, multiplying it by `i` to get them spaced out for example.